# The SitesList.xml on archive.org for the Jan 2016 data dump is blank

Tags: bug, status-completed, data-dump

See https://archive.org/download/stackexchange, specifically:

[image]

It looks like what used to be called `Sites.xml` is now called `SitesList.xml`. Presumably it's supposed to have the same information however it doesn't appear to have uploaded correctly as it's zero bytes.

Could this be uploaded pretty please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sites.xml is back in action - thanks for the heads up! I'll get that empty SitesList.xml removed shortly.

Comment: Thanks. That's some quick service!

Comment: But what caused this weird bug? :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard the name - the dump procedure was dumping the SitesList table (doesn't exist), not Sites. Not sure why that changed, but the 1 bug caused both symptoms. Old file has now been removed.